# Saving images from Django database in a management command

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

[I've found out how to load images from the file system *into* Django](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/dec/03/loading-django-files-from-code/), but how do you get them out?

I've figured out how to get stuff from the database in my management command and can do a query like:

```
for m in my_models.objects.filter(get=some):
    image = m.image 
    # How do I copy this to another non-django location?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images (or other `FileField`s) are actually regular files stored in somewhere (like a file system or a block storage like S3). Assuming that your files reside on the server's file system, you can use the `path` property to get the original file path and use Python shell utilities to copy it to another location:

```
import shutil

for m in my_models.objects.filter(get=some):
    image = m.image 
    shutil.copy(image.path, '/var/tmp/')
```